# Compute the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{1+i\sqrt3}+\sqrt{1-i\sqrt3}\right)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> Compute the degree of the extension $$\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{1+i\sqrt3}+\sqrt{1-i\sqrt3}\right)$$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Note the radicals extend over both the imaginary and real parts.
I've looked at splitting fields and theorems about extension fields but I have no idea what to do, like at all here. It makes sense to me for something like $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}\mkern1.5mu)$$ or something like that, but I'm lost here. All I know is to find the minimal polynomial. We also have not studied Galois theory yet, I found explanations elsewhere but they referenced Galois so I don't really understand them. Any concrete place to start would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: Take the degree of the minimal polynomial

Comment: yeah I mention that. I just don't know how to find the minimal polynomial for this.

Comment: Take the square of this number. A surprised result.

Comment: Oh, I thought you knew how to find the minimal polynomial.  Take @BernardPan's advice

Comment: Yes. I spent quite some time squaring it yesterday... kept getting the same wrong answer. Now when I do it I get 6, so the minimal polynomial would be $$x^2-6$$, right? I feel silly.

Comment: I don't see that your Question has any connection to finite fields.  If it's all the same to you I'd remove that tag. The expression you've written for a simple field extension to $\mathbb Q$ is ambiguous in that a nonzero complex number will have two square roots.  So a good starting point would be to address that.

Comment: $x^2-6$ is right

Comment: Write those complex numbers in polar form, and you should see the light. Mind you, it sure looks the field you get depends on the choice of branch of the square roots. What Hardmath said!